# About the proof of existence of minimal polynomials of algebraic extensions in Hungerford, Algebra, an Introduction

Tags: abstract-algebra

I think there might be some slight inaccuracies in this proof:
[image]

[image]

So to be strictly accurate, S should be the set of all "nonconstant, nonzero polynomials". But the problem is that it is entirely possible that if we apply the division algorithm for polynomials at the final step, that the remainder $r(x)$ is in fact a constant polynomial that is just $u$ itself. In that case $r(x)$ would still have $u$ as a root, but it would not contradict anything since $r(x)$ would not be in the set $S$.

However, I think this can be easily resolved if we require that $u$ be in $K\backslash F$ (not in F).

Comment: But constant polynomials (other than the zero polynomial) don't have roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remainder cannot be a non zero constant because of the hypothesis that $u$ is a root of both $p$ and $g$.